# how to read json format data from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AZnQp/8/).

How  to calculate the currencies values by reading data from the `localStorage`?
can anyone tel me steps to achieve this target?

i have jason data obtained by calling remote websites as below

```
{
    "list": {
        "meta": {
            "type": "resource-list",
            "start": 0,
            "count": 168
        },
        "resources": [{
                "resource": {
                    "classname": "Quote",
                    "fields": {
                        "name": "USD/KRW",
                        "price": "1062.280029",
                        "symbol": "KRW=X",
                        "ts": "1396294510",
                        "type": "currency",
                        "utctime": "2014-03-31T19:35:10+0000",
                        "volume": "0"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "resource": {
                    "classname": "Quote",
                    "fields": {
                        "name": "SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY",
                        "price": "0.050674",
                        "symbol": "XAG=X",
                        "ts": "1396287757",
                        "type": "currency",
                        "utctime": "2014-03-31T17:42:37+0000",
                        "volume": "217"
                    }
                }
            }


        ]
    }
}
```

i am actually learning how to use javascript by dealing with localstorages. I am a serverside programmer, this is my 3rd day of javascript programming. Hope someone can help me here

Comment: use this function `JSON.parse.` to get data back in `JSON` form otherwise its just `string` in `json` form

Comment: @BluAngel could not understand what you mean, can you update my fiddle!

Comment: Currently in your example you store all `json` data in `localStorge` that you got from `server`. Now you just want to get data back from there(localStorage)?

Comment: posted answer if still any confusion than you can ask i will try to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `localStorage.setItem('all_currencies',JSON.stringify(d));` this line converts your `JSON` `Object` to `String` so it can store in `localStorage`
Now for get data back from there you have to write

```
var jsonStringFromLS = localStorage.getItem('all_currencies');
```

Now in `jsonStringFromLS` you have all data in string form to convert into `Object` pass this value into following function

```
console.log(JSON.parse(jsonStringFromLS));
```

from above line you get your data back in `JSON` `object` form so you can now process this object.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AZnQp/9/)

Comment: oh! now i understood what you said. But again how to convert currencies  as shown in fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/AZnQp/9/  ?

Comment: Now you can process your `json` object using some like `for loop` or `for(key in data) loop (foreach)`

Comment: also check this it will increase your understanding http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/

Answer (score 5):

`JSON.stringify` is a serialization function. The unserialize function is called `JSON.parse`.

Comment: don't know what you are telling me to do? Can you please tell me in detail